# System load on headless server is 2 despite CPU being 100% idle

Tags: nvidia

My computer is consistently showing a load of 2+ when completely idle.

Importantly, this has changed at some recent point. The load would previously show 0.x when doing nothing.

I've read that load under Linux is a little more abstract than just "CPU consumption", so it may not necessarily be 2 cores running flat out, but I am having trouble tracking down what is pushing that load up, and I'm wondering whether it's something to be concerned about.

<s>The only unusual thing that has happened recently - besides a power failure - are the NVIDIA drivers auto-updating. I suspect the drivers may be the cause, but it may be something entirely different?</s> **(UPDATE: Uninstalling all nvidia drivers, then rebooting, still results in 2.0 load at idle.)**

Here is what 'top' shows:

```
top - 10:52:21 up 17:19,  1 user,  load average: 2.11, 2.23, 2.18
Tasks: 405 total,   1 running, 404 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 128172.1 total, 123776.2 free,   4116.7 used,    279.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap: 244198.3 total, 244198.3 free,      0.0 used. 123088.9 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    293 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:49.72 nv_queue
    380 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:33.05 l2arc_feed
    548 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:21.51 txg_sync
      1 root      20   0  166672   8448   5248 S   0.0   0.0   0:01.40 systemd
...
```

And 'w' or 'uptime' often show a load of precisely 2.00:

```
 11:16:15 up 17:43,  1 user,  load average: 2.00, 2.00, 2.02
```

Output of 'sudo vmstat 5':

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd      free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy  id wa st
 1  0      0 129697456   3088 224968    0    0     3    28   14   16  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697544   3088 224980    0    0     0   272  239  270  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224980    0    0     0  2147  253  341  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224984    0    0     0   245  195  238  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224984    0    0     0   821  209  259  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224984    0    0     0     0   81   77  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224984    0    0     0     0   69   73  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224984    0    0     0     0   65   66  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 129697320   3088 224984    0    0     0   259  198  244  0  0 100  0  0
```

Since noticing the unusual load, I have tried the basics, and more:

- Reboot
- Power cycle
- apt upgrade + reboot
- Uninstalling all Nvidia drivers
- zpool scrub, both rpool and bpool
- Hard power off for 30+ minutes
- Reset BIOS settings

... with no change in the 2.0 load when the system is idle.

System config:

- Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (desktop version, but with X disabled)
- Linux xxx 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600G
- 128GB RAM
- 2 x Nvidia P40 GPU
- ZFS with 2 X 2TB HDD + 128GB NVMe SSD (cache)
- NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  535.161.07  Sat Feb 17 22:55:48 UTC 2024

**Note that booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS live off a USB stick returns (after a few minutes) to a load of 0.00!!!**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "nv_queue": See https://reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/legy9n/nvidia_gpu_drivers_are_making_my_computer_stutter/gmet7jv/ For "l2arc_feed" and "txg_sync", you can try switching from ZFS to ext4

Comment: The 2.0 is misleading because it can never be greater than 1.0 (100% CPU). You need to divide 2.0 by the number of virtual CPU cores. So in my case 2.0 / 8 (4 physical cores of 2 virtual each) = .25 or 25% CPU load.

Comment: @daniel-t Thanks for the tip about nv_queue, but so far all I can find is workarounds for X (my machine is headless, and X is disabled). Important to note this load didn't happen as of a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: The load average doesn't relate directly to CPU usage. From the uptime(1) manpage: `System load averages is the average number of processes that are either in a runnable or uninterruptable state.`.  I understand what you're saying about this being a recent change, but are you actually seeing increased CPU usage?  What is reported by`vmstat` from the procps package?  Invoke it as `vmstat 5` to see continuous reports at five-second intervals. ==edit== Did you disable the graphical desktop with `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user`?

Comment: @klode I have added the vmstat output to the OP. The command 'sudo systemctl get-default' reports 'multi-user.target'

Comment: I booted a live Ubuntu off USB and the load goes to 0.00 as expected - even with the GUI running. I've also tried powering off for 30 minutes, and reloading BIOS defaults, but 2.00 persists on my install. I don't know if there's something else that was auto-updated at the same time as the nvidia drivers that is causing this issue. I'm stumped.

Comment: "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS live off a USB stick [...] a load of 0.00": That doesn't use ZFS

Comment: @daniel-t True, my install has ZFS, but that doesn't explain how (1) occasional writes (less than 1MByte/sec average) would consume so much load, (2) why the load sits at 2.00 (the "new" idle?), and (3) why it has only changed recently. Both top and vmstat suggest there's literally (almost) nothing happening. Is there some other way to drill down into what is causing the load?

Comment: All I know is "l2arc_feed" and "txg_sync" are from ZFS. Your ZFS might be an out-of-tree driver, and you can check whether a recent update changed it

Comment: The vmstat output is definitive: your system is actually idle.  The "us" column is CPU  time in user space; it's 0.  The "sy" (system time) is 0.  Lastly, "id" (idle time) is 100%.  I do understand that the 2.0 load average makes it seem as if your system is busy, but in your current situation, it's merely an annoyance.  BTW this "load average = CPU utilization" confusion occurs even among computer programming professionals; I've had many such discussions over the years.  I suggest that you change how you check whether a system is busy.  :-)  I can make this an answer if you'll accept it.